# Python SAC plot w/ grid

Tags: python, plot

I'm required to use the information from a .sac file and plot it against a grid.  I know that using various ObsPy functions one is able to plot the Seismograms using `st.plot()` but I can't seem to get it against a grid. I've also tried following the example given here "[How do I draw a grid onto a plot in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209568/how-do-i-draw-a-grid-onto-a-plot-in-python)" but have trouble when trying to configure my x axis to use UTCDatetime.  I'm new to python and programming of this sort so any advice / help would be greatly appreciated.

Various resources used:
"http://docs.obspy.org/tutorial/code_snippets/reading_seismograms.html"

"http://docs.obspy.org/packages/autogen/obspy.core.stream.Stream.plot.html#obspy.core.stream.Stream.plot"

Answer (score 1):

The `Stream`'s `plot()` method actually automatically generates a grid, e.g. if you take the default example and plot it via:

```
from obspy.core import read
st = read()  # without filename an example file is loaded
tr = st[0]   # we will use only the first channel
tr.plot()
```

[image]

You may want to play with the `number_of_ticks`, `tick_format` and `tick_rotation`parameters as pointed out in http://docs.obspy.org/packages/autogen/obspy.core.stream.Stream.plot.html.

However if you want more control you can pass a `matplotlib` figure as input parameter to the `plot()` method:

```
from obspy.core import read
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

st = read('/path/to/file.sac')
st.plot(fig=fig)

# at this point do whatever you want with your figure, e.g.
fig.gca().set_axis_off()

# finally display your figure
fig.show()
```

Hope it helps.