# Want to draw grid, python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, ekg

I want to draw grid table with python but now I can draw ECG graph and I cannot draw grid.
Now>> My ECG graph 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZHr2.png)

In Future, I want red grid with ECG graph,.
Could you give me some advice to draw red line?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rliSf.jpg)

Comment: Please add the code you already have, so we can base our assistance on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I draw a grid onto a plot in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209568/how-do-i-draw-a-grid-onto-a-plot-in-python)

Comment: As Klaus said, it's impossible to guide you without seeing the code you have for generating your current plot. Please update the question with this code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw grid lines behind matplotlib bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357798/how-to-draw-grid-lines-behind-matplotlib-bar-graph)

Answer (score 2):

This might be too late for you, but I hope this can be helpful:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# plot your ECG

# Turn on the minor ticks on
ax.minorticks_on()

# Make the major grid
ax.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', color='red', linewidth='1.0')
# Make the minor grid
ax.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', color='black', linewidth='0.5')
```