# Bubble-plot weighted 2d scatter plot data onto mesh/grid

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

## Background

I have a 2D set of "raw" data points, in the form of an array, i.e.:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
 [1, 2, 4, 2, 1],
 [0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

The data represents a circle-like "mass distribution" plot in 2D space. The x-y coordinates represent the x-y distribution of data points, and the value at each x-y coordinate is the mass/intensity measured at that data point.

I would like to plot this data, **using only Python,** ([**only at the integral x-y intersections**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209568/how-do-i-draw-a-grid-onto-a-plot-in-python/37896687)), like in the plot below, but using my own x-y scatterplot data, rather than plotting a 2D line/function.

[image]

Additionally, I would like to combine the ["specify dot size" logic from another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827650/pyplot-scatter-plot-marker-size/47403507), which allows me to specify the dot size on a "per-sample/value" basis, i.e.:

[image]

---

## Question

How do I combine the logic above to render a data set like so:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
 [1, 2, 4, 2, 1],
 [0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

As something like this, via `matplotlib`/`pyplot` (discrete-domain, discrete-range, continuous-valued):
[image]

---

## Extra

[How can I re-use the above data set to generate a heatmap of the same data (i.e. continuous-domain, continuous-range, continuous valued)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369492/generate-a-heatmap-in-matplotlib-using-a-scatter-data-set)

[image]

Or, more like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by first creating a `meshgrid` defining your x and y coordinates and then using the `data` array to define the size of your points. The entries which are `0` will not be shown because of 0 size. I am using a rescaling factor of 100 to just enlarge the points.

Complete working code:

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
 [1, 2, 4, 2, 1],
 [0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])

mesh = np.arange(len(data))
x, y = np.meshgrid(mesh, mesh)
plt.scatter(x, y, s=data*100)
plt.xticks(range(len(data))) # To put ticks at integer values
plt.yticks(range(len(data))) # To put ticks at integer values
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Generating a heat map**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data here

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(len(data)), np.arange(len(data)))
plt.scatter(x, y, s=data*100, c=data, cmap=cm.Oranges)
plt.xticks(range(len(data)))
plt.yticks(range(len(data)))
```

[image]

Comment: Beautifully simple. One last question: how can I enable the x/y lines at integer values? They aren't rendering on my system, so I may as well explicitly set them.

Comment: Additionally, is there a simple way to re-use the same data set to generate a heat map? Thank you.

Comment: @DevNull: I included your preferences in the answer now. Hope your question is answered now.

Comment: I was able to enable the grid lines via `plt.grid()`. One last question, is there an easy way to convert your second heatmap graph to something with greater resolution, similar to the most recent (i.e. bottom) image I added to the question? Thank you.

Comment: @DevNull: To get the greyish background and white grid lines as in my answer, you can use seaborn as `import seaborn as sns` and then `sns.set()`

Comment: The question is definitely answered. Thank you. If there's a way to convert it to the "modified" heat map I described, so much the better.

Comment: @DevNull: This greater resolution would require more datapoints and some interpolation. I would request you to post a different question regarding this issue.

Comment: Will do. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @DevNull: I tried something and may be you like it or at least get some hint: Try `plt.contourf(x,y,data)` and you will see something similar to your last figure. Now you will see the point I am making: you would need some circular interpolation to have circles. This might not be so straightforward and deserves to be a standalone question on its own

Comment: @DevNull: This might be of interest to you: `plt.imshow(data,interpolation='bicubic')`. You can try different interpolation schemes to see what suits your desires better

Comment: This is perfect!