# How can I plot an NxN grid with Python?

Tags: python, grid

Hi everybody I am trying to do something easy in Python but for me, nothing seems to be easy. What I want to do is to plot a grid of nxn automatically that is when I change the numbers in (make) for instance (4,4) to plot a 4X4 grid if I write (10,10) to plot a 10X10 grid, and so on. My code is below. Any help, please

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

def make(X,Y):

    x, y = np.indices((X,Y))


    sqr = (x==0) & (y==0)


    for i in range (X):
         for j in range (Y):
         
              sqr = (x==i) & (y==j) 
          
          
    plt.show()
    plt(sqr)

make(10,10)
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the expected output (manually)?

Comment: well, I don't know how to add a picture in my comment. I just want to have a plot with a grid. When I choose (3,3) to get a 3X3 grid of 9 squares for (4,4) a 4X4 grid of 16 squares, for (3,4) a 3x4 Grid with 12 squares, and so on

Comment: but what is a "square"? is it a 0? or do you want to have an actual grid using matplotlib?

Comment: Yes, exactly I want an actual grid using matplotlib. Sorry for my ignorance  but I have started to learn Python 3 months ago so I am not familiar with it

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209568/how-do-i-draw-a-grid-onto-a-plot-in-python)